# Jquery Slider : Object [object Object] has no method 'slider'?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am probably missing something trivial but I cannot find any flaw, I have a Jquery UI slider

```
$(function()
        {
            $("#slider").slider(
                {
                    min : 0,      // Have a box that just takes in the price
                    max : 500,
                    change: function(event,ui)
                    {
                        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
                    }
                });
            $("#amount").val( "$" + $("#slider").slider("value") );
        });
```

my html code is

```
<label for="amount">Your Price:</label> 
<input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; font-weight: bold;" />
<div id="slider" class="slider"></div>
```

but my slider does not display , I keep getting this error in chrome

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slider'
```

I have also included the jquery header files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you included the jquery ui header file? they are not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the jQuery UI plugin for slider after jQuery include. That is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PATH_TO_JQUERY_UI"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you , I  did not notice the jquery UI script